# Change cross table color programmatically in spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

Dears,

I have a color rule based on a column. It checks whether a word is contained in a column and color it. Basically 'contains' rule in a categorical column.
I have a requirement to change this using python script.

Please see attached picture to see the configuration.

[Screenshot of crosstable color rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEAwk.jpg)

For example i want to change colour of construction to red in above screenshot